# Databound listbox not able to scroll windows phone

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a databound list box and a listpicker in my application. I hid the listpicker and will be opened only when an event is triggered.

Initially the listbox will be populated with some values (More than 10 values). i tried to scroll the list. But I couldn't. When I Click on the list and drag the mouse up, the list goes further down. The effect is more or like pulling down the list.

The xaml code is as follows. please help.

```
<StackPanel>
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding List_OC}" Visibility="Collapsed" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>

<ListBox x:Name="Requests1" ItemsSource="{Binding Details_OC}" SelectionChanged="Requests_SelectionChanged">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="450">
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                   <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                   <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsComplete, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="3" Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked" />
              <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                   <TextBlock x:Name="WorkOrderID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding WORKORDERID}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="date" Text="{Binding Path=DUEBYTIME, Converter={StaticResource dateConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
              </StackPanel>
              <TextBlock x:Name="Subject" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding SUBJECT}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
              <TextBlock x:Name="Requester" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding REQUESTER}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
              <TextBlock x:Name="PriorityLabel" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text=" * Priority : " VerticalAlignment="Top" />
              <TextBlock x:Name="Priority" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding PRIORITY}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
           </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and I solved the problem by replacing the Stackpanel that contains your listbox by a Grid .

It worked for me.

Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: Thanks it works.. If you could say the reason it would be helpful.

Comment: I found this information on stackpanel :" At StackPanel will "stack" items visually in a "panel."  It does not include scrolling controls, but you can use it to easily present a limited list of items.  It handles the layout of controls in one direction." .So no scrolling controls...